# How to change the default delay on the boot menu from 30 seconds to 5 seconds on windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I saw my friend's computer wait for only 5 seconds on the boot menu screen (where you select which OS to boot), while mine delays for 30 seconds.  How can I change this?

Comment: If you friend's computers are newer than yours, probably they are using a UEFI BIOS, which can deliver faster boot times than a legacy BIOS.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suspect that you may be talking about the delay during the "Select an operating system" screen during boot, that defaults to 30 seconds.

To change this:

1. open the System control panel (shortcut: <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>)
2. select Advanced System Settings from the left hand menu:

   [image]
3. Click the Settings button in the Start-up and Recovery group:

   [image]
4. Edit the Time to display list of operating systems to suit:

   [image]

Comment: I use MSConfig to access the same boot menu

Comment: *System control panel* is also available by right-clicking on *My computer*, then selecting *Properties*

Answer (score 0):

From an elevated command prompt (not PowerShell):

```
bcdedit.exe /set {bootmgr} timeout <integer>
```

Example:

```
bcdedit.exe /set {bootmgr} timeout 31
```

Answer (score -2):

The boot time depends on the hardware and the also the softwares that are run on start up.Remove the unnecessary softwares from the startup and it may decrease your computers's boot up time

Comment: I think you misunderstood his question. He was asking about the "count down timer" delay.